# Override form data when editing an object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to override the fields when editing an object in Django.

When I try to edit an existing category for example, the fields name and description are loaded from the database. What I want to do is displaying another data in the fields rather that the data stored in the database. There is any way to do that ?

The question is strange, you may wonder why I need that. It's for a school project and it's the only way to do what I want to do.

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Are you editing the object in the admin section, or have you written your own (model-based) forms through which objects are being edited?

Comment: I'm editing the object in the admin section using the default form to add and edit objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this but I have done it before. Create a custom ModelForm for your model, set it on the ModelAdmin class and implement the form class like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            self.fields['myfield'].initial = 'custom value'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

If that's not what you meant, just reply and I'll update it.